# Not able to navigate from one view to other

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to navigate from one view to another in UI5 application but I am not able to do so. I recently created a copy of an existing view *A* and renamed it to *B*. Then I copied the controller of *A* and renamed it as controller of *B*. I now want to navigate from *A* to *B* view. I have declared the view *B* in `routes` just like *A* (renamed wherever necessary) but I am still not able to navigate. When I click on button in view *A*, I want to display *B*. But nothing happens. Console shows no error either. What can be the issue?

In Controller of *A*:

```js
buttonClick: function(event) {
  vc.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("stockDetails", {
    "companyId": vc.companyId,
    "stockroomId": vc.stockroomId,
    "order": vc.orderNo
  }, false);
},
```

In manifest.json:

- Under `routes`:

  ```js
  {
    "name": "stockDetails",
    "pattern": "company/{companyId}/stockrooms/{stockroomId}/order/{order}",
    "titleTarget": "",
    "greedy": false,
    "target": [
      "menu",
      "stockDetails"
    ]
  }
  ```
- Under `targets`:

  ```js
  "stockDetails": {
    "viewType": "XML",
    "transition": "slide",
    "clearAggregation": true,
    "viewName": "stockroom.stockDetails", //stockDetails View B
    "viewLevel": 2,
    "controlAggregation": "pages",
    "controlId": "app"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possible causes..

## Multiple Targets for `<App>`

It looks like you're trying to assign multiple targets (`"menu"`, `"stockDetails"`) to the same aggregation (`"pages"`) at the same time. Unless it's using master-detail layout or a `parent` target is involved, try to assign only the right target for the right aggregation. In case of `sap.m.App`:

```json
{
  "name": "stockDetails",
  "pattern": "...",
  "target": "stockDetails"
}
```

Otherwise, you'll encounter unexpected behaviors depending on the implementation of the `routerClass` module.

## Identical Patterns

Although the route `name` may be different (`"stockDetails"`), you probably have kept the route `pattern` when copy-pasting from the source route (*A*).

If it's true, you'll need to **provide a distinct `pattern`** for the route `"stockDetails"` as well. When identical patterns exist, the first route is always taken into account over the others.*

> The sequence of the routes in the routes definition is important. As soon as a pattern is matched, the following patterns are ignored.<sup>[[src]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/902313063d6f45aeaa3388cc4c13c34e)</sup>

[Here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.PatternMatching/preview), you can try to define two identical patterns and set the hash accordingly. You'll see that only the first pattern is matched which would be, in your case, the view *A*.

---

* Unless the property `greedy` is active in one of the other routes.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the pattern and now I am able to navigate. But I have a different issue now.  In my new view B 's controller, if I try to access any input control saying " this.getView().byId("abc").getValue() it does not return any value.also if I try to setVisible any button nothing happens. This is happening with controls that I added new in View B. For controls that are same as View A, and if I try to access them it is possible. I am wondering if I have to something in particular when I make copies of views and controllers? Could you please help me. I am stuck from quite some time.

Comment: @THI Glad I could help. About the next issue: I can guess where the error might be but instead of trying to solve the problem here, I'd say it's better to open a new question since the original question is already resolved and people with a similar issue would find the possible solutions faster. Nevertheless, my guess is that the `controllerName` in the view *B* is not pointing to the newly created controller *B* but still to the controller *A*. Please, check also the module name you passed in: `(Base)Controller.extend(<moduleName>, {})` whether it's pointing to the right file name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using the right event for button click. 
Can you try using the "press" event, and not the "buttonClick" event?

Before that, try putting a "console.log("Event Firing OK") within your buttonClick event handler, and check the console if the message is coming up. If not, you know the event is not even getting fired, and hence, your navigation code is never executed.

REFERNCE : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Button/events/press

Best Regards,
Gopal Nair.

Comment: buttonClick is the name of the function handling the press event. So he can certainly call his eventhandler function buttonClick. press is the correct attribute to use in your XML view